# How to determine the schema of a REST service?

Tags: sql-server, json, rest

I'm attempting to build a process that will import JSON data returned from a REST service into a SQL Server 2016 database on a scheduled basis (every 5 mins).  I'm aware there's a new SQL 2016 function called OPENJSON which can probably handle importing the data, but I'm concerned about setting up the target tables in the database since I don't know what the REST service could possibly return.

Is there a way to lookup the full schema (required and optional fields) of a REST service so the tables created in SQL server can be built to handle all of the types of data the REST service could return?

Am I just being foolish since the REST schema could potentially always change?
If that's the case, how could any process rely on REST data, is any of it set in stone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the rest service? If so then you can publish a schema using an API Explorer tool such as swagger. You can also version the end-points and dto's to avoid contract changes. If you don't have control over the rest service and it is subject to change then you'll unfortunately need to validate the data to contract that your side has agreed upon before importing any data from it.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I don't have any control over the rest service.  I'm attempting to import data from Google and Bing APIs.  I guess I'm used to having a WSDL.  I was looking for something like this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870778.aspx  The part that confuses me a bit is, how can anyone build useful code to consume REST data if you're never guaranteed what might be returned?

Comment: I understand your confusion. There must be documentation for the API that described the request and response.